# ng-repeat is not working

Tags: angularjs, json

i can fetch array like this and i can see it on my console

```
0 :  Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object
12
:
Object
13
:
Object
14
:
Object
15
:
Object
16
:
Object
17
:
Object
18
:
Object
```

and each array there is value like this for example 0th array contain this

```
0:object
    id :  8726
    name : "aman"
    slug : "aman"
    type  :  "Drug"
```

Angular js

```
 $scope.keyup = function (data) {
   $http({
        url: 'myapi?q='+data,
     method: "GET", 
    }).success(function(response){

      $scope.results = response.data;
    });


 $scope.$watch('userInput',function(){
     var key =$scope.$$watchers[0].last;
     $scope.keyup(key) }); //this is because ng-keypress was not working but this is not an issue
```

HTML

```
  <a ng-repeat="item in results" ng-href="#">
                <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            </a>
```

i can see the array in console but i dont know why ng-repeat is not working

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bctc.png)

---

its done.. idk why but the solution is so so so bad

```
$scope.results = response.data;
 $rootScope.vars = $scope.results
```

Comment: Is the html tag in the controller where keyup function is written?

Comment: `i can fetch array like this and i can see it on my console` Did you mean `$scope.results`?

Comment: Small example demostrating the issue would be great: http://plnkr.co/

Comment: can you log that $scope.results

Comment: @Shiva yes i did and its coming on console

Comment: @YuryTarabanko help me out i idk y its not working

Comment: $scope.results =[ ]; in your controller in start or try use $scope.$digest() in http success function.

Comment: @Love-Kesh not working

Comment: @YuryTarabanko see the log in the image below

Comment: aman.sri65@gmail.com

Comment: check inbox for the req

Comment: @Sajeetharan its not there,,, tell me urs i am sending you from my side

Comment: sajeefx@gmail.com

Comment: @Sajeetharan sent

Comment: Are you sure the page is used by that controller, what happen when you write  $scope.test = 'test' and bind it to the same page?

Comment: i did not get anything

Answer (score 0):

This may be silly, can you write like this while get result from api as below,

```
$scope.keyup = function (data) {
    $http({
        url: 'myapi?q='+data,
        method: "GET", 
    }).success(function(response){
      $scope.results = response.data.data;
    });
}
```

> ***Note:*** you are missing close brace on your keyup function.  (There is a
>   chance to miss while copy code to stack. Please ignore if it is so.)

Answer (score 0):

Below one can help you.

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp', []);
  app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){  
  $scope.searchMov = "Batman";

         $scope.data = [{'name':'aa','id':1, 'address':'xxx'},{'name':'bb','id':2, 'address':'zzz'},{'name':'cc','id':3, 'address':'aaaa'},{'name':'dd','id':4, 'address':'bbbb'}];
         
   // console.log($scope.data); // see console

$scope.keyup = function () {
    $http({url: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+$scope.searchMov+'&page=1',
        method: "GET", 
    }).success(function(response){
      $scope.results = response;
    });
};
  function init(){
  $scope.keyup();
  };
  init();
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <div>
     {{data}}<br><br>
     <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <div ng-repeat="dat in data | filter: search">{{dat.id}} {{dat.name}}   {{dat.address}}</div>   
   </div>
  <br><br> 
  Search Movies Here: <input type="text" ng-model="searchMov" ng-change="keyup()">
  
  <p>{{results.Error}}</p>
   <div ng-repeat="rs in results.Search">
   <div style="padding:2px;margin:2px;border:1px solid #789898"><p>{{rs.Title}} {{rs.Year}}</p>
   <img ng-src="{{rs.Poster}}" style="width:100px;height:100px">
   </div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-repeat` code is working fine as per the provided `JSON`.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    var response = [
     {    
       id :  8726,
       name : "aman",
       slug : "aman",
       type  :  "Drug"
     },
     {
       id :  8727,
       name : "aman1",
       slug : "aman1",
       type  :  "Drug1"     
     },
     {
       id :  8728,
       name : "aman2",
       slug : "aman2",
       type  :  "Drug2"     
     },
     {
       id :  8729,
       name : "aman3",
       slug : "aman3",
       type  :  "Drug3"     
     }
    ];
    
    $scope.results = response;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <a ng-repeat="item in results" ng-href="#">
      <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use track by

```
<a ng-repeat="item in $scope.results track by $index" ng-href="#">
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        </a>

<a ng-repeat="item in $scope.results track by item.id" ng-href="#">
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        </a>
```

Comment: it's working... https://jsfiddle.net/mubo2wuj/
you should remove $scope